# Does a taylor polynomial always have a non-zero remainder?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

A bit of a silly question but it isn't really covered in my book and can't seem to find this question anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean a non-zero remainder? But of course the Taylor Series for a polynomial is exact.

Comment: @lulu yes sorry, that is what I meant. A non-zero remainder.

Comment: Well, like I say...that first order Taylor polynomial for $f(x)=x$ is $x$ which is exact.

Comment: I think you should look at the definitions of the Taylor _polynomial_ and the Taylor _series_ of a function. A Taylor polynomial contains a finite number of terms since it is a full-fledged polynomial. And thus there is no remainder.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that we are dealing with a smooth function $f$ here, if $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a\in D_f$, then the Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$ has a non-zero remainder if and only if $f$ is *not* a polynomial function or if it is a polynomial function whose degree is greater than $n$.